# Retrieving the current PTP settings of an Ubuntu machine

Tags: scripting, ubuntu-18.04, daemon, master, ptp

I have an Ubuntu machine (18.04) with [PTPd](https://manpages.debian.org/testing/ptpd/ptpd.8.en.html) installed. I want to write a script that can determine what PTP settings have been set previously.

Specifically, I want to find information on the master PTP server that this machine is locked to (if it is locked at all), such as its IP address.

As far as I can tell, PTPd does not store that sort of info in a conf file anywhere (in fact, my PTPd doesn't even have a conf file because I haven't created one for it); if it did, I could parse that conf file for the information.

Is there an existing command, or a simple script that can get this information for me?